# Implementation questions

Tags: discussion

Over on Crypto's Meta site we are discussing [implementation requests/lists](https://crypto.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191/implementation-list-questions). One commenter pointed out something on our FAQ. It says that implementation considerations should be Security.

That said, are the sorts of questions linked to in my question on Crypto's meta site on topic here?

Answer (score 2):

In general, we do have a range of implementation questions here, but I don't think the 3 you linked to would fit that well for a couple of reasons:

1. List questions are generally not a good fit
2. Asking for specific software may be time bounded / too localised

Have a look at the [cryptography](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cryptography) tag to see the questions we typically do handle here. Examples include choice of hash function, use of crypto functions in implementations, risks of using certain functions etc